# Shell scripting - how to call python shell commands in if statement

Tags: python, shell, docker, entry-point

I'm currently writing on my docker-entrypoint.sh script. The script determines a service_type which is a env. variable depending on the returned value the actual application start will differ.

within the if statement I have several commands to check if the landscape is ready for useage.
I'm also using Python here but always running into the follwoing issue:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 128:
>   warning: here-document at line 30 delimited by end-of-file (wanted
>   `EOF')
>
> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 129:
>   syntax error: unexpected end of file

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

############### App ###############

if [ "$SERVICE_TYPE" = "app" ]
then
  echo "I'm a Application instance, Hello World!"

  ...

  echo "Checking if System User is setup"
  {
  python manage.py shell <<-EOF
  from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

  User = get_user_model()  # get the currently active user model
  User.objects.filter(user='$SYS_USER').exists() or User.objects.create_superuser('$SYS_USER', '$SYS_USER')
  EOF
  }

  ...

############### Celery Worker ###############

elif [ "$SERVICE_TYPE" = "celery-worker" ]
then
  echo "I'm a Celery Worker instance, Hello World!"

  ...

############### Celery Beat ##################

elif [ "$SERVICE_TYPE" = "celery-beat" ]
then
  echo "I'm a Celery Beat instance, Hello World!"
  ...


fi
```

How can I execute my python shell cmd within the if statement so that I basically have the same result as If i wouldn't use it in a if statement like so:

```
echo "Checking if System User is setup"
{
cat <<EOF | python manage.py shell
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()  # get the currently active user model
User.objects.filter(user='$SYS_USER').exists() or User.objects.create_superuser('$SYS_USER', '$SYS_USER')
EOF
}
```

Comment: The token that ends a heredoc needs to be the first (and only) thing on its line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here-doc end-tokens can't have leading white space. Also your script inside the heredoc shouldn't have any leading whitespace

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

############### App ###############

if [ "$SERVICE_TYPE" = "app" ]
then
  echo "I'm a Application instance, Hello World!"

  echo "Checking if System User is setup"
  {
  python manage.py shell <<-EOF
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()  # get the currently active user model
User.objects.filter(user='$SYS_USER').exists() or User.objects.create_superuser('$SYS_USER', '$SYS_USER')
EOF
  }

############### Celery Worker ###############

elif [ "$SERVICE_TYPE" = "celery-worker" ]
then
  echo "I'm a Celery Worker instance, Hello World!"

############### Celery Beat ##################

elif [ "$SERVICE_TYPE" = "celery-beat" ]
then
  echo "I'm a Celery Beat instance, Hello World!"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks foir your fast answer, has solved my Problem. Never really was aware of this before